# Django - cant connect to local MySQL Server through socket

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, django

I’m using Django Bitnami Stack on Amazon EC2. I’m attempting to sync the database for the initial setup but I am having problems.

When running the following  command I receive an error message:
`Python manage.py syncdb`

**"Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")**

I understand this as not being able to establish a connection to MySQL server. However when I run this from the command line I can connect:

`Mysql –u root –p // "Then entering my password”`

Here are the database settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'djangostack',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'bitnami'
}
}
```

I've tried to restart MySQL server using `sudo service mysqld restart` but I recieve a message stating that mysql is an unrecognized service.

Here is the my.cnf file:

```
[mysqladmin]
user=root

[mysqld]
basedir=/opt/bitnami/mysql
datadir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/data
port=3306
socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
tmpdir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp
bind-address=127.0.0.1

[mysqld_safe]
mysqld=mysqld.bin

[client]
port=3306
socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock

[manager]
port=3306
socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/manager.pid
default-mysqld-path=/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin


!include /opt/bitnami/mysql/bitnami/my.cnf
```

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Wow, that did it! Thanks! Why did that make such a big difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to the host `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost`. `localhost` has special meaning for MySQL on a Unix based OS.